# msal-flutter kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mainActivity has not been initialized

Tags: android, flutter, azure-ad-msal

I am using [msal-flutter](https://github.com/moodio/msal-flutter) in one of the flutter app.

environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
flutter: ">=1.10.0"

Getting following error in Android app.

```
E/MethodChannel#msal_flutter(28234): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#msal_flutter(28234): kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mainActivity has not been initialized
E/MethodChannel#msal_flutter(28234):    at com.signify.msal_flutter.MsalFlutterPlugin.initialize(MsalFlutterPlugin.kt:230)
E/MethodChannel#msal_flutter(28234):    at com.signify.msal_flutter.MsalFlutterPlugin.onMethodCall(MsalFlutterPlugin.kt:125)
E/MethodChannel#msal_flutter(28234):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#msal_flutter(28234):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#msal_flutter(28234):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/MethodChannel#msal_flutter(28234):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#msal_flutter(28234):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/MethodChannel#msal_flutter(28234):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
E/MethodChannel#msal_flutter(28234):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
E/MethodChannel#msal_flutter(28234):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#msal_flutter(28234):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/MethodChannel#msal_flutter(28234):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I guess method registerWith is not calling.

Following is the code using in MsalFlutterPlugin class:

```
 @Suppress("SpellCheckingInspection")
 public class MsalFlutterPlugin: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {

  private lateinit var channel : MethodChannel

   override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), "msal_flutter")
channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
}

companion object {

lateinit var mainActivity : Activity
lateinit var msalApp: IMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication

fun isClientInitialized() = ::msalApp.isInitialized

@JvmStatic
fun registerWith(registrar: Registrar) {
  Log.d("MsalFlutter","Registering plugin")
  val channel = MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "msal_flutter")
  channel.setMethodCallHandler(MsalFlutterPlugin())
  mainActivity = registrar.activity()
}

fun getAuthCallback(result: Result) : AuthenticationCallback
{
  Log.d("MsalFlutter", "Getting the auth callback object")
  return object : AuthenticationCallback
  {
    override fun onSuccess(authenticationResult : IAuthenticationResult){
      Log.d("MsalFlutter", "Authentication successful")
      Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
        result.success(authenticationResult.accessToken)
      }
    }

    override fun onError(exception : MsalException)
    {
      Log.d("MsalFlutter","Error logging in!")
      Log.d("MsalFlutter", exception.message)
      Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
        result.error("AUTH_ERROR", "Authentication failed", exception.localizedMessage)
      }
    }

    override fun onCancel(){
      Log.d("MsalFlutter", "Cancelled")
      Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
        result.error("CANCELLED", "User cancelled", null)
      }
    }
  }
}

private fun getApplicationCreatedListener(result: Result) : IPublicClientApplication.ApplicationCreatedListener {
  Log.d("MsalFlutter", "Getting the created listener")

  return object : IPublicClientApplication.ApplicationCreatedListener
  {
    override fun onCreated(application: IPublicClientApplication) {
      Log.d("MsalFlutter", "Created successfully")
      msalApp = application as MultipleAccountPublicClientApplication
      result.success(true)
    }

    override fun onError(exception: MsalException?) {
      Log.d("MsalFlutter", "Initialize error")
      result.error("INIT_ERROR", "Error initializting client", exception?.localizedMessage)
    }
  }
}
}

override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
val scopesArg : ArrayList<String>? = call.argument("scopes")
val scopes: Array<String>? = scopesArg?.toTypedArray()
val clientId : String? = call.argument("clientID")
val authority : String? = call.argument("authorityURL")

Log.d("A_MsalFlutter","Got scopes: ${scopes.toString()}")
Log.d("A_MsalFlutter","Got cleintId: $clientId")
Log.d("A_MsalFlutter","Got authority: $authority")

when(call.method){
  "logout" -> Thread(Runnable{logout(result)}).start()
  "init" -> initialize(clientId, authority, result)
  "acquireTokenInteractively" -> Thread(Runnable {acquireToken(scopes, result)}).start()
  "acquireTokenSilent" -> Thread(Runnable {acquireTokenSilent(scopes, result)}).start()
  else -> result.notImplemented()
}
}
private fun acquireToken(scopes : Array<String>?, result: Result)
{
Log.d("MsalFlutter", "acquire token called")

// check if client has been initialized
if(!isClientInitialized()){
  Log.d("MsalFlutter","Client has not been initialized")
  Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
    result.error("NO_CLIENT", "Client must be initialized before attempting to acquire a token.", null)
  }
}

//check scopes
if(scopes == null){
  Log.d("MsalFlutter", "no scope")
  result.error("NO_SCOPE", "Call must include a scope", null)
  return
}

//remove old accounts
while(msalApp.accounts.any()){
  Log.d("MsalFlutter","Removing old account")
  msalApp.removeAccount(msalApp.accounts.first())
}

//acquire the token
msalApp.acquireToken(mainActivity, scopes, getAuthCallback(result))
```

}

private fun acquireTokenSilent(scopes : Array?, result: Result)
{
Log.d("MsalFlutter", "Called acquire token silent")

```
// check if client has been initialized
if(!isClientInitialized()){
  Log.d("MsalFlutter","Client has not been initialized")
  Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
    result.error("NO_CLIENT", "Client must be initialized before attempting to acquire a token.", null)
  }
}

//check the scopes
if(scopes == null){
  Log.d("MsalFlutter", "no scope")
  Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
    result.error("NO_SCOPE", "Call must include a scope", null)
  }
  return
}

//ensure accounts exist
if(msalApp.accounts.isEmpty()){
  Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
    result.error("NO_ACCOUNT", "No account is available to acquire token silently for", null)
  }
  return
}

//acquire the token and return the result
val res = msalApp.acquireTokenSilent(scopes, msalApp.accounts[0], msalApp.configuration.defaultAuthority.authorityURL.toString())
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
  result.success(res.accessToken)
}
```

}

private fun initialize(clientId: String?, authority: String?, result: Result)
{
Log.d("MsalFlutter", "inside the initialize block")
//ensure clientid provided
if(clientId == null){
Log.d("MsalFlutter","error no clientId")
result.error("NO_CLIENTID", "Call must include a clientId", null)
return
}

```
//if already initialized, ensure clientid hasn't changed
if(isClientInitialized()){
  Log.d("MsalFlutter","Client already initialized.")
  if(msalApp.configuration.clientId == clientId)
  {
    result.success(true)
  } else {
    result.error("CHANGED_CLIENTID", "Attempting to initialize with multiple clientIds.", null)
  }
}

// if authority is set, create client using it, otherwise use default
if(authority != null){
  Log.d("MsalFlutter", "Authority not null")
  Log.d("MsalFlutter", "Creating with: $clientId - $authority")
  PublicClientApplication.create(mainActivity.applicationContext, clientId, authority, getApplicationCreatedListener(result))
}else{
  Log.d("MsalFlutter", "Authority null")
  PublicClientApplication.create(mainActivity.applicationContext, clientId, getApplicationCreatedListener(result))
}
```

}

private fun logout(result: Result){
while(msalApp.accounts.any()){
Log.d("MsalFlutter","Removing old account")
msalApp.removeAccount(msalApp.accounts.first())
}
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
result.success(true)
}
}

override fun onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
}
}

msal_auth.dart::

```
class MsalAuth {
```

static const MethodChannel _channel =
const MethodChannel('msal_flutter');

//Configuration parameters
String _clientId, _authority, _redirectURI;

MsalAuth(String clientID, {String authorityURL, String redirectURL}){
throw Exception("Direct call is not allowed. Please use PublicClientApplication static method");
}

MsalAuth._create(String clientId, {String authority, String redirectURI}) {
_clientId = clientId;
_authority = authority;
_redirectURI = redirectURI;
}

static Future publicClientApplication(String clientID, {String authorityURL, String redirectURL}) async{
var res = MsalAuth._create(clientID, authority: authorityURL, redirectURI: redirectURL);
await res._initialize();
return res;
}

Future _initialize() async {
var res = <String, dynamic>{'clientID': this._clientId};
//if authority has been set, add it aswell
if (this._authority != null) {
res["authorityURL"] = this._authority;
}
if (this._redirectURI != null) {
res["redirectURI"] = this._redirectURI;
}

```
try {
  await _channel.invokeMethod('init', res);
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  throw _convertException(e);
}
```

}

/// Acquire a token interactively for the given [scopes]
Future acquireToken(List scopes) async {
var res = <String, dynamic>{'scopes': scopes};
try {
final String token = await _channel.invokeMethod('acquireTokenInteractively', res);
return token;
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
throw _convertException(e);
}
}

/// Acquire a token silently, with no user interaction, for the given [scopes]
Future acquireTokenSilent(List scopes) async {
var res = <String, dynamic>{'scopes': scopes};
try {
final String token =
await _channel.invokeMethod('acquireTokenSilently', res);
return token;
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
throw _convertException(e);
}
}

Future logout() async {
try {
await _channel.invokeMethod('logout', <String, dynamic>{});
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
throw _convertException(e);
}
}

MsalException _convertException(PlatformException e) {
switch (e.code) {
case "CANCELLED":
return MsalUserCancelledException();
case "NO_SCOPE":
return MsalInvalidScopeException();
case "NO_ACCOUNT":
return MsalNoAccountException();
case "NO_CLIENTID":
return MsalInvalidConfigurationException("Client Id not set");
case "INVALID_AUTHORITY":
return MsalInvalidConfigurationException("Invalid authroity set.");
case "CONFIG_ERROR":
return MsalInvalidConfigurationException(
"Invalid configuration, please correct your settings and try again");
case "NO_CLIENT":
return MsalUninitializedException();
case "CHANGED_CLIENTID":
return MsalChangedClientIdException();
case "INIT_ERROR":
return MsalInitializationException();
case "AUTH_ERROR":
default:
return MsalException("Authentication error");
}
}
}